# Custom UITableView reorder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I'm wondering if anyone has a link to a good tutorial or can point me in the right direction to recreate the 'drag to reorder' cells in a UITableView like Epic Win App.  The basic idea is you tap and hold on a list item and then you drag to where you want the item to be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how to achieve this, if we have multiple sections with one row for each section???? Please do help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is pretty straight forward - which is probibly why there is no explicit tutorial on the matter.

Just create the UITableView normally, but set the `showsReorderControl` of each cell to TRUE. When you go into editing mode (normally by pressing the "edit" button and setting the "Editing" value of the UITableView to TRUE) - the reorder bars will appear in the cells.

Note:

If your data source implements `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` - and it returns "NO" - the reorder bars will not appear.

You will also need to implement  `–tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` in the data source delegate.

Comment: The one thing I would like to be able to do is supersede the button and make the whole cell the button.  So you can just drag the cell around.  Do you know any way of how to do that?  Or a stepping stone of how to do that?

Comment: It is very easy to subclass UITableCellView into anything you want - so it would just be a matter of making yours with your own reorder bar button/area.

Comment: Were you able to rewire the bar/button area as Brad suggests?  As far as I can see it is far from trivial to intercept or resize the reorder button area.  It looks like you can use Apple's entire methodology here or completely reorder your own from scratch.

Comment: I agree with Thomson, this is far from a simple problem, and is much more in depth than using a couple tableView delegate methods, and writing a subclass. If you claim something to be easy, please provide the proof that it is easy.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way, using the built-in methods, is as follows:

First, set your table cell to have shows reorder control on. Simplest example (using ARC):

This is assuming `NSMutableArray *things` has been created somewhere else in this class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"do not leak me"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [things objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Implement your two `UITableViewDelegate` methods, like this:

This method tells the tableView it is allowed to be reordered

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

This is where the tableView reordering actually happens

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    id thing = [things objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [things removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [things insertObject:thing atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

}
```

and then somehow, somewhere, set editing to true.  This is one example of how you can do this.  The tableView must be in editing mode in order for it to be reordered.

```
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {
    self.table.editing = YES;
}
```

Hope that serves as a concrete example.

Comment: The question clearly stated to give a custom reorder option, not the default.

Comment: @Unome No. The OP chose the Accepted Answer, which is basically a more summary version of my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The accepted answer like you said is a watered down version of what the question asked for. I've posted a working subclass of a UITableView.

Comment: I apologize. In retrospect my comments were rude. I was simply frustrated that the answers did not provide help to what I was looking for as a User. Your question was carefully and well written, and provided a good answer, albeit not the answer I wanted. +1

Answer (score 4):

This solution here will function similar to the Reminders app on OSX which allows you to reorder cells by holding and dragging anywhere.

I've created a subclass of UITableView that allows you to drag and reorder the cells without having to have `editing` on or use the standard reorder handles.

The basic idea is I use the touches began and touches ended to get which cell was tapped, I then create a fake view that is really just a screenshot of the view you tapped and move it back and forth, swapping the cells in the background. When the user lets go I then unhide the original view.

```
class ReorderTableView: UITableView {

var customView:UIImageView?
var oldIndexPath:NSIndexPath?

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch1 = touches.first else{
        return
    }

    oldIndexPath = self.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touch1.locationInView(self))
    guard (oldIndexPath != nil) else{
        return
    }
    let oldCell = self.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.oldIndexPath!)

    customView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, touch1.locationInView(self).y - 20, self.frame.width, 40))
    customView?.image = screenShotView(oldCell!)
    customView?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    customView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    customView?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1)

    self.addSubview(customView!)
    oldCell?.alpha = 0
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch1 = touches.first else{
        return
    }
    let newIndexPath = self.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touch1.locationInView(self))
    guard newIndexPath != nil else{
        return
    }
    guard oldIndexPath != nil else{
        return
    }
    if newIndexPath != oldIndexPath{
        self.moveRowAtIndexPath(oldIndexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
        oldIndexPath = newIndexPath
        self.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.oldIndexPath!)!.alpha = 0
    }
    self.customView!.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, touch1.locationInView(self).y - 20)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.customView?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.customView = nil
    guard (oldIndexPath != nil) else{
        return
    }
    self.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.oldIndexPath!)!.alpha = 1
}

func screenShotView(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {

    let rect = view.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,true,0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -view.frame.origin.y);
    self.layer.renderInContext(context!)
    let capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return capturedImage
}

}
```

In the end you can reorder cells without having to use the handles. This can be extended for different gestures, or modes depending on the use case, but I left this as a vanilla version. Let me know if you have any questions.

**Update:**

Some caveats I found. It is very important you figure out how you want to use scrolling and modify this accordingly. For instance, when I mocked it out I set `scrollingEnabled = false.` In the long run I did want scrolling, so I changed the code to only run this functionality on a press longer than 0.25 (I used some timers to do this). I would then temporarily disable scrolling during this period, and re-enable upon completion.

Comment: What makes you think the OP wants this? The accepted answer uses handles. Thank you.

Comment: his question: "The basic idea is you tap and hold on a list item and then you drag to where you want the item to be" did not specify he wanted to use handles, and the title "Custom Reorder" implies not using the default methods. I had a similar issue, and neither answer here helped me. I tried to contribute an answer that would help those that have similar problems. An accepted answer does not = right answer. Thank you.

Comment: All good. If you want to add another answer which shows another approach that's perfect. No need to smack around the other answers to promote yours +1

Comment: I understand, my comments were made prior to even attempting to answer the question, and my intent was never to promote my answer.

Comment: It's all good. So what's of these hard-coded numbers like `20` in this answer?