# Is there a way to drag the items of a UITableView up and down to change their order ?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to drag the items of a UITableView up and down to change their order ?

See the example (the small arrows indicate the items are movable): http://cl.ly/972U

Or should I use another user interface widget ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. This other [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011163/custom-uitableview-reorder) goes over the same thing. Basically, you create the UITableView just like you've been doing, but when you create a cell, set the `showsReorderControl` value of the cell to TRUE and the reordering bars will appear.

Comment: I've actually found this article and it works, but it's a lot of code so I was wondering if it is correct implementation for a draggable table with (add/remove buttons.. I forgot to ask about this)